# How do I create an adjacency matrix for bidirected mode and graph mode?

Tags: r, simulation

so here I am trying to simulate a network according to the Erdos-renyi model and I'm trying to create two adjacency matricies one bidirected mode and the other in graph mode. This here is my function

```
er.graph <- function(n, tprob, mode){

# check that n is a positive integer

if(!is.numeric(n) || n <= 0 || n != round(n)){

stop("n must be a positive integer")

}

# check that tprob is a probability

if(!is.numeric(tprob) || tprob < 0 || tprob > 1){

stop("tprob must be a probability")

}

# check that mode is either undirected or directed

if(!mode %in% c("undirected", "directed")){

stop("mode must be either undirected or directed")

}

# create empty adjacency matrix

adj.matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n)

# fill in adjacency matrix

for(i in 1:(n-1)){

for(j in (i+1):n){

if(runif(1) < tprob){

adj.matrix[i,j] <- 1

# for undirected networks, fill in the other side of the matrix

if(mode == "undirected"){

adj.matrix[j,i] <- 1

}

}

}

}

return(adj.matrix)

}
```

and the output of the code when it is run through the function specifications below should look like the picture at the bottom:

```
set.seed(0)
er.graph(6.5)
er.graph(6, tprob = 1.1)
er.graph(6, tprob = 1, mode = 'directed')
er.graph(8, tprob = 0.2)
er.graph(8, tprob = 0.5, mode = 'undirected')
```

one of the errors I get is

```
Error in er.graph(6.5) : n has to be a positive integer
```

which means something is missing in the function above.
Here is the image(result I want), which I'm unsure of how to extract it in R.
The top is bidirected and bottom is graph
[image]

Comment: A few things I noticed.  6.5 is not an integer, so that should generate an error.  1.1 is not a probability and thus should generate an error.  The third `er.graph()` call works for me (produces an upper triangular matrix of ones).  The fourth command does not specify a `mode` and thus should fail.  The final `er.graph()` call uses `mode = "graph"` where `mode`, by your code can only be one of `"undirected"` or `"directed"` and thus should fail.  Replacing `"graph"` with `"undirected"` produces a result. I'm not sure where the problem is.

Comment: How do I specify that the probability doesn't just have to be between 0 and 1?

Comment: and how do I add a condition where it can ignore the mode?

Comment: What do you want the code to do when it ignores the `mode` argument?

Comment: We will probably have to create a separate code that can handle: er.graph(6.5)
er.graph(6, tprob = 1.1)
er.graph(8, tprob = 0.2)

Comment: when it ignores the mode argument, it still needs to create an adjacency matrix, but it may have NA values in it.

Comment: You can allow other values of `tprob` by removing one (or more) of the stop conditions.  Right now, you have: `if(!is.numeric(tprob) || tprob < 0 || tprob > 1)` If you remove `|| tprob > 1` from the above, it would force `tprob` to be positive, but not bounded by 1.  If you took out both `|| tprob < 0` and `|| tprob > 1`, then there would be no constraint on `tprob` other than that it is numeric.

Comment: When `mode` is ignored, should the adjacency matrix be directed or undirected?